# How to tell when mysqldump is complete

Tags: php, ftp, backup, mysql

Each night I do a backup of my database using the following command. I ftp this backup file offsite every night, but I have no idea when it is safe to begin the ftp session since I don't know how long the dump takes.

Is there any way with `php` to tell when the `mysqldump` is done - for example testing whether `$filename` is still in use or querying mysql for dumps in progress?

Thanks in advance.

```
$command = "mysqldump -h " . DB_SERVER . " -u ". DB_USER ." -p". DB_PASS ." --add-drop-table --quick --set-gtid-purged=OFF " . DB_NAME . " > ". $filename; 

$result = passthru($command);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a backup log file?

```
$command = "mysqldump -h " . DB_SERVER . " -u ". DB_USER ." -p". DB_PASS ." --add-drop-table --quick --set-gtid-purged=OFF " . DB_NAME . " > ". $filename; 
$result = passthru($command);

$file = fopen('backup-file-name', 'a'); // can specify full path
fwrite($file, date('M-d-Y h:i:s') . " -- backup finished \n");
fclose($file);
```

Or something like this:

```
// open file and say it's in progress
$file = fopen('backup-file-name', 'w'); // can specify full path
fwrite($file, date('M-d-Y h:i:s') . " -- backup in progress \n");
fclose($file);

$command = "mysqldump -h " . DB_SERVER . " -u ". DB_USER ." -p". DB_PASS ." --add-drop-table --quick --set-gtid-purged=OFF " . DB_NAME . " > ". $filename; 
$result = passthru($command);

// open file and say that backup is done
$file = fopen('backup-file-name', 'w'); // can specify full path
fwrite($file, date('M-d-Y h:i:s') . " -- backup finished \n");
fclose($file);
```

---

**EDIT:**

The PHP code executed after `passthru()` only triggered after `passthru()` is finished.

Another useful info is that `passthru()` can take a second argument `return_var` that returns the status of the command.

Couple notes:

- 0 means the status returned successfully for Unix commands.
- The [second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) for `passthru()` returns value by reference, so please pass a declared variable to the function.

Example:

```
$command_status = 'N/A';
$result = passthru($command, $command_status);
// then check if $command_status value === 0
// maybe log the status of the command as well
```

Comment: From your answer, I gather then that `passthru()` doesn't return control back to the php script until the dump is done. Correct? I had presumed it was a dump and run. If so, your examples would work just fine. I use this as part of a cron job - hopefully that won't interfere (e.g. timeouts or whatever).

Comment: I don't think there will be an issue because you're using cron. However using log files to store information about cron jobs is essential for debugging and finding out what happened if something goes wrong. (Note: you can even send an email after the even is done: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: The answer was way simpler than I imagined. I was already logging the beginning of the backup job. It is a simple matter to log the ending as well. Thanks for updating your answer to make it more complete.